# Convert string into other encoding

Tags: delphi, character-encoding

I read usernames from physical device. All usernames it's Base64 encoded strings with cyrilic symbols. Somehow device do wrong convert symbols into utf8, so i try to fix it in client side to show correct usernames in GUI.

Problem is that part of usernames converts successful, but some part raise exceptions when i try to do it.

Here is simplified example how i do it:

```
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

  function Convert(ABase64String : string) : string;
  begin
    var xWin1251 :=  TEncoding.GetEncoding(1251);
    try
      var DecodedStr : string := TNetEncoding.Base64String.Decode(ABase64String);
      var DecodedBytes := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(DecodedStr);
      var ConvertedBytes := TEncoding.Convert(TEncoding.UTF8, xWin1251, DecodedBytes);

      Result  :=  TEncoding.UTF8.GetString(ConvertedBytes);
    finally
      xWin1251.Free;
    end;
  end;

const
  s1 = '0KDRmtCg0ZHQodCD0KHQi9Cg0ZQg0KDRmtCg0ZHQoNGU0KDRldCgwrvQoMKwIA==';
  s2 = '0KDigJjQodGT0KDCttCg0ZHQoNCF0KHQitCh0IPQoNGU0KHigJMg0KDRmtCh4oCT0KE=';
begin
  ShowMessage(Convert(s1));
  ShowMessage(Convert(s2));
end;
```

`s1` - converts fine.

Debug values:

```
DecodedStr  'РњРёСЃСЋРє РњРёРєРѕР»Р° '
DecodedBytes    (208, 160, 209, 154, 208, 160, 209, 145, 208, 161, 208, 131, 208, 161, 208, 139, 208, 160, 209, 148, 32, 208, 160, 209, 154, 208, 160, 209, 145, 208, 160, 209, 148, 208, 160, 209, 149, 208, 160, 194, 187, 208, 160, 194, 176, 32)
ConvertedBytes  (208, 156, 208, 184, 209, 129, 209, 142, 208, 186, 32, 208, 156, 208, 184, 208, 186, 208, 190, 208, 187, 208, 176, 32)
Result  'Мисюк Микола '
```

`s2` - raise exception with message `No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page` instead of returning value `Бужиньскі МіС`.

Debug values:

```
DecodedStr  'Р‘СѓР¶РёРЅСЊСЃРєС– РњС–С'
DecodedBytes    (208, 160, 226, 128, 152, 208, 161, 209, 147, 208, 160, 194, 182, 208, 160, 209, 145, 208, 160, 208, 133, 208, 161, 208, 138, 208, 161, 208, 131, 208, 160, 209, 148, 208, 161, 226, 128, 147, 32, 208, 160, 209, 154, 208, 161, 226, 128, 147, 208, 161)
ConvertedBytes  (208, 145, 209, 131, 208, 182, 208, 184, 208, 189, 209, 140, 209, 129, 208, 186, 209, 150, 32, 208, 156, 209, 150, 209)
```

I found old program that handle with text encoding. It convert all values fine with operation called `UTF8->WIN`, so i definitely know that it's possible.

What did I miss?

Comment: You need to decode the base64 to bytes not a string. By using TEncoding.UTF8 the way you are, you are just compounding the problem further. Decode to raw bytes, fix the bytes if needed, and then decode the bytes to a string using the correct encoding. If the bytes are not UTF-8 then don't use TEncoding.UTF8 at all

Comment: I'd start by determining the text encoding of the decoded base64 bytes. It's not clear that you understand that yet.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That's a first that i did when saw the problem. Unfortunatly got exactly same result, but more code, thats why i post this version of code.

Comment: @RemyLebeau "Decode to raw bytes" - i did try that, got same DecodedBytes as we see in question. "fix the bytes if needed" - that's is a problem, i don't know how to do it. I did try to decode correct and wrong values in bytes and compare it. Figure out that in 90% of cases when I got byte 208 than next byte must be increased on 38 to have correct value in win1251 encoding, but does not works in all cases.

Comment: @OleksandrMorozevych I posted an answer for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I played around with your data, and your decoding code is correct.

The base64 you are being given decodes to UTF-8 bytes, which must then be decoded to UTF-16 and then *re-encoded* to Windows-1251, and then the resulting bytes must be *interpreted* as UTF-8 instead of as Windows-1251.

Your `Convert()` function is doing exactly this - although you don't need the 1st `TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes()` call as the base64 decodes to UTF-8 (`Base64String.Decode()` assumes UTF-8 when returning a UTF-16 string), so you can omit that step completely, eg:

```
function Convert(ABase64String : string) : string;
begin
  var xWin1251 :=  TEncoding.GetEncoding(1251);
  try
    //var DecodedStr : string := TNetEncoding.Base64String.Decode(ABase64String);
    //var DecodedBytes := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(DecodedStr);
    var DecodedBytes := TNetEncoding.Base64.DecodeStringToBytes(ABase64String);

    var ConvertedBytes := TEncoding.Convert(TEncoding.UTF8, xWin1251, DecodedBytes);
    Result := TEncoding.UTF8.GetString(ConvertedBytes);
  finally
    xWin1251.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Now, with that said, this approach works *perfectly* for your 1st example Unicode string `'Мисюк Микола '`, because the base64 for that string is correct.

For your 2nd example Unicode string `'Бужиньскі МіС'`, this approach works *almost* perfectly.  The base64 data actually decodes properly as above up to characters `'Бужиньскі Мі'`, however the base64 for the last character `'С'`, which is normally encoded in UTF-8 as bytes `$D0 $A1`, is being decoded to a single byte `$D1` instead of 2 bytes `$D0 $A1`. That is why you get the "No mapping" error from the final `TEncoding.UTF8.GetString()`.

So, it is not a mistake in your decoding code - you are simply decoding *faulty input* to begin with!

The *correct* base64 for the Unicode string `'Бужиньскі МіС'` under the above scheme *SHOULD BE*:

`'0KDigJjQodGT0KDCttCg0ZHQoNCF0KHQitCh0IPQoNGU0KHigJMg0KDRmtCh4oCT0KDQjg=='`

NOT:

`'0KDigJjQodGT0KDCttCg0ZHQoNCF0KHQitCh0IPQoNGU0KHigJMg0KDRmtCh4oCT0KE='`

(ie, `DQjg==` instead of `E=` at the end)

So, this is a mistake in whoever is sending you the base64 in the first place.  The correct solution is to fix the source where the base64 is coming from, not fix your decoder (because it is not broken).

Comment: thank you for spending your time for my problem!